# SciPy module error w = np.zeros(M) TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, scipy

In scipy module I am facing this error:

```
File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\windows.py", line 5
58, in blackmanharris
    w = _cos_win(M, [0.35875, 0.48829, 0.14128, 0.01168])
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\windows.py", line 1
13, in _cos_win
    w = np.zeros(M)
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to `np.zeros()` is the number of zeroes in the resulting array. For example, `np.zeroes(3)` will return `np.array([0,0,0])`. So it makes no sense to pass a float into it, you cannot get a fractional number of zeroes in your array. And your `M` is a float. So teh way to fix it is to figure out why you are passing a float instead of an integer.

Comment: thanks it helped. I passed 'M' in blackmanharris function (scipy lib) as integer